# Blackberry Simulator and MDS

Tags: blackberry, mds-cs

Has anybody got the BB simulator and MDS simulator to work?

I have the MDS installed and 4 BB phone sim's.  For some reason, when I first install the BB sim it might work and then it will stop working.

Has anybody had this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console running the MDS simulator?

Comment: Also, can you define "it will stop working"

Comment: I don't see any errors.

As for "stop working". I will be using a sim and browsing a site and i will see the mds scroll.  Then I will click on a link and the request times out and i don't see any action on mds.

Answer (score 3):

The first time I used both, **BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0** and its version of MDS-CS, it worked very well. After a couple of simulator reloads to test a Browser-Push application, the **9800 simulator** stopped connecting with the Mobile Device Service Simulator. All rules are important, but in my case, rule #3 allowed me to connect the simulator's internet browser **after deactivating the WiFi** connection

1. MDS should be running *before* you start the simulator; and it listens on port 8080, so make sure nothing else is listening on that port before you start it.
2. The simulator seems to pick up the MDS location from the `rimpublic.property` file (under `MDS/config`), which is part of the MDS install, and `rimpublic.property` needs to have the machine's fully qualified host name in it, not `localhost`.
3. If you've started your simulator without the MDS running, you will need to remove the **.dmp** files in [installroot]/[phonemodel]. This problem often happens with BlackBerry JDE version 6.0.0.

These rules seem to have work for me so far.

Comment: Also, apparently, port 8443 which had been taken up by VisualSVN on my machine.  I stopped the service, restarted the MDS + simulator, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several common mistakes when using MDS simulator with BlackBerry Simulator.

1. If you're opening network http connections you need to add "deviceside=false" parameter to your urls
2. In case you're behind proxy, you have to add several configuration parameters to enable MDS Simulator check them out [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800738/800792/801079/How_To_-_Configure_the_MDS_simulator_to_work_behind_a_proxy.html?nodeid=800740&vernum=4)

Answer (score 1):

I just spent 2 days trying various of the tips online about MDS (and there are many) but none helped me.

For me, the solution was to **turn off network registration** upon simulator launch in eclipse.

Edit: this has helped in some situations, but MDS still not always stable.

(posted in case someone with my problem googles to this page)