# Blackberry Simulator Network issue on Windows7/64bit/32bit(on vmfusion), what to do?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

i have Windows 7 64bit on my PC and i have Windows 7 32bit on my vmfusion on mac.

The problem is as follows, if i run early version of blackberry simulators (not touchscreen, but with scroll ball), i do not get network access. I try to run MDS as i have read on forums, but it looks like MDS quits, and i still have no network acess.

The new simulators, let me just run them, and i dont even need to lunch mds, i get access to network with no problem. But the project i am working on, requires me to test mobile site again older blackberry devices.

So here is what i have done so far:

1. Made sure i have following for java: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_22" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22", do i need anything else?
2. set up environment path variable to bin folders: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22\bin;
3. installed everything at separate location as administrator (D:\Programs\Research In Motion), so not to have any write/read issues.
4. installed MDS and then BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 4.5.0 - 4.5.0.81 (8100)

now i try to run MDS first, and i see two cmd/three windows popping up one after another, and closing right away. I start up simulator and everything starst great, but when i go to browser and try to navigate to web resource i get an error "Unable to connect to the selected Mobile Data Service, please try again later".

Little edit:

I have moved my effort to XP, which solved MDS start up issue, but simulator still cant establish network connection. See screen shot.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry Simulator and MDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455760/blackberry-simulator-and-mds)

Comment: i have moved my efforts to XP, i got MDS runing, but still have same darn network issue on 8300 simulator....

Comment: We havent been on JDK 5 for some time. I was going to say the current version was 6.26 but I had a peek at the Oracle site and they are offering 7. Might be the problem.

Comment: Will have to try, will see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: the only reason i installed JDK 5 is because i read about compatibility issues runing MDS 4.1.4 with anything above JDK 5 on forums.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/4-5-Simulator-Browser-App-Unable-to-Connect-to-MDS-Sim/td-p/311608

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653701/blackberry-mds-simulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet-in-the-simulator

Comment: I was looking at these articles last night... i do run 4.5 simulators i will try 4.2 may be that will solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start MDS you will have to start a console with "Run as administrator" then go to the path where you installed mds and start the .bat file from your elevated console.

[image: Run as admin]

Here the console command to start MDS.

[image: run.bat]

## EDIT

When MDS is running you can connect to it with your browser to see what is not working

goto : http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Thanks Michael, will try it later, but even with my XP efforts, which made MDS run, i still cant get simulator on XP access the network resources, is it possible that it could be port blocking of some sort? If so, is there a way to tell MDS or Simulator which port to use?

Comment: I am currently doing this in xp (vm), as i have moved my efforts there. In terms of seeing the page, it says that there are  0 devices connected. See the attachment i added to my question.

Comment: @GnrlBzik make sure that the mobile network is activated on the phone. I just tested with a sim 8330 and it works well on Windows 7 64 bit with latest JDK6

Comment: Alright, let me start up my Win7 again, and crete everything there again.

Comment: B do i need to add path variables? as i was doing for bin folder in jdk?

Comment: @GnrlBzik, the only thing I have in my path is the jdk/bin folder

Comment: thanks for your help. I will let you know how it goes, once i reinstall fresh jdk6 and BB mds and simulator

Comment: @GnrlBzik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2330/discussion-between-michael-b-and-gnrlbzik)

Comment: Thank you so much : ) every thing is working. The difference in this set up is that i only have one jdk installation, and simulator runs of 4.2 OS + everything started through powershell as you sugested in run as administrator mode.